# select command in mysql returns an empty row even though the entry exist in table

Tags: mysql

When I run the below query in phpmyadmin it returs 0 rows even the entry exists on the table

```
SELECT * FROM `default_companyshare` WHERE `comp_symbol` = "ACEDBL"
```

Comment: ELECT * FROM `default_companyshare` WHERE `comp_symbol` = 'ACEDBL'

Comment: how about `SELECT * FROM `default_companyshare` WHERE trim(`comp_symbol`) = 'ACEDBL'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in case you have some space-padding in your database:

```
SELECT * FROM `default_companyshare` WHERE `comp_symbol` like "%ACEDBL%"
```

You can also try trimming your result:

```
SELECT * FROM `default_companyshare` WHERE trim(`comp_symbol`) = "ACEDBL"
```

Answer (score 0):

You clearly have some issue with the string comparison.  Start with:

```
SELECT *
FROM `default_companyshare`
WHERE upper(`comp_symbol`) like '%ACEDBL%';
```

This will show you all the symbols that contain that string.  Then figure out if the problem is leading/trailing spaces, collation conflicts, hidden characters, or something else.